# Powershell Printing weird values

Tags: powershell

Every now and then, my powershell script prints below out of blue. I rechecked many times and I've no function or script to print this. Could someone please help me if this 
is a expected behaviour of powershell?

```
PSPath            : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\SOMEDIR\
PSParentPath      : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\SOMEDIR\
PSChildName       : SOMEFILENAME
PSProvider        : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem
PSIsContainer     : True
Name              : SOMEFILENAME
Parent            : Archieve
Exists            : True
Root              : \\SOMEDIR
FullName          : \\SOMEDIR\
Extension         :
CreationTime      : 17/05/2013 4:05:15 PM
CreationTimeUtc   : 17/05/2013 6:05:15 AM
LastAccessTime    : 17/05/2013 4:05:15 PM
LastAccessTimeUtc : 17/05/2013 6:05:15 AM
LastWriteTime     : 17/05/2013 4:05:15 PM
LastWriteTimeUtc  : 17/05/2013 6:05:15 AM
Attributes        : Directory
BaseName          : SOMEFILENAME
Mode              : d----
```

Below is the suspected powershell snippet:

```
foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem $path*.* -Include *.csv){ 

        if (!(Test-Path $archieveFolder) )
        {
            #1. Create config archieve directory
            New-Item -Path $archieveFolder -Force -ItemType Directory
        }
}
```

Comment: No this is not expected. There must be something within your code that's prompting this to happen, it will be difficult to help you as I can't see your code, but try outputting debug messages at various points in your script to try to pin point the line that causing this prompt

Comment: When you try `Get-Job` is there anything returned? Also what's definition of `prompt` function? (Look at `Get-Content function:\prompt`)

Comment: Something like ` Get-Item .\somedir | FL *` can return this output.

Comment: Yep this is the line, but on what scenario does it return this

Comment: @Myagdi Add the rest of the code... the suspect is innocent and we have no evidence to charge him

Comment: So the problem is `prints out of blue`? Out of which color it should print instead?

Comment: @Neolisk "out of the blue" is an [idiom meaning "unexpectedly or for no apparent reason"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_the_blue_(idiom\))

Comment: @alroc: Thanks, but it still does not make sense to me. `The script prints something for no reason` is not a good explanation of the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

New-Item outputs the item it creates. If you don't want it, cast to [Void] or pipe it to Out-Null.

```
New-Item -Path $archieveFolder -Force -ItemType Directory | Out-Null
```

Comment: @Myagdi Great, glad to help. It's good to accept the answer if you consider your question answered.